# Fetch JSON from Google Maps Autocomplete and Submit it into Django Form Data

Tags: javascript, json, django, google-maps, fetch

For my website, I want to place a Google Maps autocomplete form into a page, and when the user submits the coordinates, and will send the JSON to Django forms, so it can submit it into the database.

My only issue is that I do not know how to get the latitude and longitude from the Google Maps application, and submit it into Django.

Here's the code for the Google Maps Autocomplete:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
            * element that contains the map. */
            #map {
            height: 100%;
            }
            /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
            html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
            #description {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
            }
            #infowindow-content .title {
            font-weight: bold;
            }
            #infowindow-content {
            display: none;
            }
            #map #infowindow-content {
            display: inline;
            }
            .pac-card {
            margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
            border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Roboto;
            }
            #pac-container {
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            margin-right: 12px;
            }
            .pac-controls {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px 11px;
            }
            .pac-controls label {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 300;
            }
            #pac-input {
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-left: 12px;
            padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            width: 400px;
            }
            #pac-input:focus {
            border-color: #4d90fe;
            }
            #title {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #4d90fe;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: 500;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
            <div>
                <div id="title">
                    Autocomplete search
                </div>
                <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
                    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
                    <label for="changetype-all">All</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
                    <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
                    <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
                    <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
                </div>
                <div id="strict-bounds-selector" class="pac-controls">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="use-strict-bounds" value="">
                    <label for="use-strict-bounds">Strict Bounds</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pac-container">
                <input id="pac-input" type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter a location">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="infowindow-content">
            <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
            <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
            <span id="place-address"></span>
        </div>
        <script>
            // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
            // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
            // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
            function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {
                  lat: 21.3000,
                  lng: 202.1460
              },
              zoom: 13
            });
            var placeMarker = {} //gets updated lat lng from the marker
            var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
            var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

            // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
            // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
            // bounds option in the request.
            autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

            // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
            autocomplete.setFields(
              ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.307, -157.858); //sets marker to honolulu
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
            infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: myLatlng,
              draggable: true,
              anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(evt) {
            placeMarker['lat'] = evt.latLng.lat()
            placeMarker['lng'] = evt.latLng.lng()
              console.log(placeMarker);
            });

            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
              infowindow.close();
              marker.setVisible(true);
              var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
              if (!place.geometry) {
                  // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
                  // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
                  window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                  return;
              }

              // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
              if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                  map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
              } else {
                  map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                  map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
              }
              marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
              marker.setVisible(true);
            var placeMarker = {}
              //gets position of marker when they type in a location
            placeMarker['lat'] = marker.getPosition().lat()
            placeMarker['lng'] = marker.getPosition().lat()
              console.log(placeMarker);

              var address = '';
              if (place.address_components) {
                  address = [
                      (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                      (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                      (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                  ].join(' ');
              }

              infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
              infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
              infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
            // Autocomplete.
            function setupClickListener(id, types) {
              var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
              radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                  autocomplete.setTypes(types);
              });
            }

            setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
            setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
            setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
            setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);

            document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
              .addEventListener('click', function() {
                  console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
                  autocomplete.setOptions({
                      strictBounds: this.checked
                  });
              });
            }
            //get directions part will use this link 
            //https://www.google.com/maps/dir//21.307,-157.858/@21.4297802,-158.1141956,10.83z
            //last half is the zoom settings; first 2 numbs are lat long.
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAzjwfZHvAzrcCsD7NOXkvgMmQmzxDQPBU&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's an example of the Google Maps Autocomplete: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

I've added a dictionary 'placeMarker' in the code and inserted the latitude and longitude, thinking there was some way to fetch the object to Django. And I know that Django can get form data once the form is submitted.

If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

the latitude and longitude are inside of `place.geometry.location` object, maybe you can put this into var and uses according your needs.